# sudo phpenmod mbstring doesn't work, /etc/php/8.1/mods-available is empty. Ubuntu-22.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-22.04, mbstring

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled$ sudo phpenmod mbstring
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled$
```

The directory is empty:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/php/8.1/mods-available$ ls
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/php/8.1/mods-available$
```

When I do `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` I get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
I checked where it was located I got this.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ whereis php8.1-mbstring
php8.1-mbstring: /usr/share/php8.1-mbstring
```

I then tried manually moving the package to `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available` but I still got an error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo phpenmod mbstring
WARNING: Directory /etc/php/8.1/cgi/conf.d doesn't exist, not enabling the module
WARNING: Directory /etc/php/8.1/phpdbg/conf.d doesn't exist, not enabling the module
WARNING: Directory /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d doesn't exist, not enabling the module
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install php8.1-mbstring`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, unfortunately without any luck.